# Concrete class is not valid in given context when passed as a type

Tags: c#

I have an implementation of an abstract class that is being passed into a function that accepts a generic `T` parameter of the specified abstract class. But for some reason it's throwing me an error saying the concrete class is not valid in the given context.

Any ideas on whats going would be appreciated.

**Helper Method**

```
public static async Task<bool> StartSingleAppService<T>(T type) where T : Service
    {
        // GetServiceMaintainer() gets a singleton of my Services list
        if (ServiceMaintainer.GetServiceMaintainer() != null)
        {
            Service service = ServiceMaintainer.GetServiceMaintainer().FindServiceByType(type);
            if (await ServiceMaintainer.StartService(service))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Usage**

```
// `UpdateService` is type not valid in the given context
await AppServices.StartSingleAppService( UpdateService );
```

**UpdateService**

```
public class UpdateService : Service
```

**Service**

```
public abstract class Service
```

**Notes:**

- The `Service` abstract class defines abstract task methods. `public abstract Task<bool> start();`
- The `Service` abstract class defines a couple member variables
- The `UpdateService` class implements the abstract methods and has a couple helper functions.

Comment: Please post the full content of the error, as well as the declaration of the `UpdateService` variable.

Comment: @JonB it's not a variable. It's the class treated as a type. and the error is nothing more than what I stated.

Comment: Are you calling method with an object of `UpdateService` class or you are passing type `UpdateService` to the method?

Comment: @visc then that's your problem. Your function takes in a parameter of that type, not the actual type itself.@JSteen's answer is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your apples and pears slightly in a twist. As it's currently declared, the method doesn't expect a type, it expects an instance of a type. What you probably want to do is remove the parameter and use a typeof-operator inside your method.

```
// argument removed here ------------------------------\/
public static async Task<bool> StartSingleAppService<T>() where T : Service
{
    // GetServiceMaintainer() gets a singleton of my Services list
    if (ServiceMaintainer.GetServiceMaintainer() != null)
    {
        Service service = ServiceMaintainer
            .GetServiceMaintainer()
            .FindServiceByType(typeof(T));
        // argument changed here --/\

        if (await ServiceMaintainer.StartService(service))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The call site changes slightly too:

```
await AppServices.StartSingleAppService<UpdateService>();
```

Comment: Thanks that did it